# google form submit script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On form submit I am trying to get the value of a record number cell set in the spreadsheet. But I am getting incorrect values in the confirmation message even though the logger displays the right value.

```
        /**
        * Gets the list of responses and display the recordNumber from the spreadsheet
        * 
       */

          function ticketNumberAlert() {
               var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

               Logger.log("form name " + form.getId() + " " + form.getTitle());
               Logger.log("form destination " + form.getDestinationId() + form.getDestinationType());

               var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId());

               var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

               Logger.log("Record Number " + lastRow);

               var lastItem = sheet.getRange('I'+lastRow).getValue();

               var newRecNum = lastItem + 1;

               Logger.log("last record number" + newRecNum);

               //form.setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for registering. Your ticket number is ' + lastItem );

               form.setCustomClosedFormMessage('Thanks for registering. Your ticket number is ' + newRecNum );

    }
```

The confirmation message display #15. But the logs display the correct incremented recordNumber value.

[14-06-01 07:06:41:430 EDT] form name 1gIxWfEQIYHSkxZQbjJHa2CTdHO8mAFwQPcBJiiEHAC8
[14-06-01 07:06:41:529 EDT] form destination 0AgZ_Q0okrzbJdG9CbzdKQTJXYTdWOXdrbWpyeWFUVlESPREADSHEET
[14-06-01 07:06:42:008 EDT] Record Number 18
[14-06-01 07:06:42:045 EDT] last record number19

Comment: suggest you use [google-apps-script] tag

Answer (score 0):

I should have used setConfirmationMessage instead of setCustomClosedFormMessage. CustomClosed form message is a message displayed when the form is not accepting any more responses.